# ReactionDisposer is not recognizing change in enum ( mobx )

Tags: flutter, mobx

After the update of  **flutter_mobx: ^2.0.6+1** and  **mobx_codegen: ^2.0.7** the ReactionDisposer is not recognizing changes in enum

```
 late ReactionDisposer _refreshDisposer;
 Completer<dynamic> refreshCompleter = new Completer();

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   _refreshDisposer = reaction((_) => _vendorStore.serviceState, (_) {
      if (_ != LoadingEnum.loading) {
        refreshCompleter.complete();
        refreshCompleter = Completer();
      }
     });
  }
```

Observer is working fine but **ReactionDisposer** is not working according to change

```
flutter :3.0.5
Dart 2.17.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new **flutter_mobx: ^2.0.6+1** and **mobx_codegen: ^2.0.7**  has no effect on the below import

```
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';
```

so to work the **ReactionDisposer** add this plugin **mobx: ^2.0.7+5** in you'r dependencies else it won't recognize the change

Comment: happy to help you